# C++ Is it possible to pass text with line breaks to a C++ program?

Tags: php, c++, command, arguments, line

I am calling a C++ program via PHP, using the system() function:

```
$use = '"' . $_POST['source'] . '"';
system("Subject " . $use);
```

where $use stores some text that might contain line breaks and that gets itself passed to the PHP program using the $_POST variable. If I pass this variable to the C++ program and the contained text has line breaks, then only the first line gets passed to the program. I tried to avoid this by using the two quotation marks, but this doesn't work. So if the input is for example

```
word 1  
word 2
```

then only word 1 is passed to the C++ program. Conversely, if the input is of the form

```
word 1 word 2
```

then of course everything works fine.

How can I solve this if there is a solution at all?

Comment: I _really really really_ hope that this is a script that won't live out in the public, but rather something that only you can access. If not, it's an open door to the server.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, To be fair, [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) handles arbitrary commands pretty well. You can run anything you want, but it's unlikely you'll accomplish anything destructive.

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($_POST['source'])`

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I use this primarily for learning purposes, so yes, only I have access to this script. Or what exactly do you mean by access? Reading the source code or is passing arguments from another program that other people could potentially have access to also too much access? None is actually the case because I do all of this stuff on my local machine, I'm just curious.

Comment: I meant if the script was going to be on a public server (where anyone can post anything they want), but if it's just on your local machine, then no worries.

Comment: @hassan $_POST['source'] is just some text that gets passed to the PHP program, the acual content is not important, the problem that I have has to do with potential line breaks because these prevent the text after the first break to be passed to the C++ program.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson What would I do if I really were up to putting this stuff on a public server? Should I use the exec() function instead? Again, just curious, because a lot of this stuff is still rather new for me.

Comment: @AlexM how do you implement your c++ program? I've wrote a quick `C` program to simulate this and worked fine, also had tested with nodejs, unfortunately I'm not familiar with c++ syntax to test it but it would help if your put your implementation .

Comment: The majority of code of my program is not important for the problem issued here. As for the problem I just wrote the ordinary int main(int argc, char* argv[]) to get the arguments and then I concatenated all of them (exept for the very first one with the index 0) in a for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `$use` for the command line

```
system("Subject " . escapeshellarg($use))
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but somehow this does not work. I have written the simplest c++ program possible in this context for testing purposes; it just gathers the passed input and displays it on the screen, but still, only the content before the first line break appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you only need to replace line breaks with spaces:

```
$use= str_replace ("\n", " ", $use);
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought about this, too, but the downside of this is that the origninal structure of the text gets destroyed, because the result of this command would be that all line breaks disappear.

Comment: yea, I am not aware about the structure well, but you can try to replace only substring, not the whole string